# Why set is not in locals, globals or vars dictionaries

Tags: python

When I try to check if a set is available in current local scope, or in global scope, I always get the below error.

```
>>my_set = set()

>>my_set in locals()
>>Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-47b6756e3345>", line 1, in <module>
    my_set in locals()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>my_set in globals()
>>Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-47b6755f5503>", line 1, in <module>
    my_set in globals()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>my_set in vars()
>>Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-47b6755f9947>", line 1, in <module>
    my_set in vars()

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

If set is not in any of these dictionaries (locals, globals or vars), where can I check if a set is defined?

Comment: The above doesn't say "not in" anything; it says "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'", which would hopefully point you in the right direction.

Comment: Why are you doing this? This is not the way to check variables in Python. Initialize it to `None` then check if it has been set to something else.

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist, I am very new to python and adjusting from java to python is still weird to me

Comment: @HishamRaghep It's not the right way in Java either. You would still initialize it to `null` and then check if the value had changed...

Comment: @Two-Bit Alchemist, Really!!...have you seen that line in the code above "my_set = set()" before posting comments??

Comment: What does that have to do with inspecting the running state of the program to "check if (something) is available in scope"? This is what I do not recommend in any language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to quote the name when checking.

```
>>> my_set = set()
>>> locals
<built-in function locals>
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', 'my_set': set([]), '__doc__': None, '__package__': None}
>>> 'my_set' in locals()
True
>>>
```